# One sql context connection through call stack

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to deploy on the SQL Server 2008 R2 two user-defined scalar-valued functions, like two exemplified below. Both of them can be invoked on its own. The first one can also be invoked from second one.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function1(string arg1)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        //... Some code here.
    }
    return true;
}

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function2(string arg1)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        bool ret1 = Function1("arg1");
        //... Some code here.
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is deployed succesfully. But if you call Function2 the following error is raised:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: The context connection is already
>   in use"

**The questions are:**

1. What and why is the best solution to call one function that gets data from database from another function which gets data from the same database (Regular connection; Acces like to common Sql Server function using SqlCommand or something else).
2. Trustworthy propery is off, so I cannot open regular connection. What is the best solution taking into account this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in the code? It looks like you have infinite recursion with Function2 calling itself. For my answer I'll assume it should call Function1.

I'm not too familiar with `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction`, but if you can overload functions then something like the following would help you.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function1(string arg1)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        return Function1(arg1, sqlCnn);
    }
    return true;
}

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function1(string arg1, SqlConnection sqlCnn)
{
    //... Some code here using sqlCnn which we won't close or dispose.
    // as it's up to the caller to do that
    return true;
}

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function2(string arg1)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        bool ret1 = Function1(arg1, sqlCnn);
        //... Some code here.
    }
    return true;
}
```

so that anything calling Function1 can use Function1(string) and it will create it's own connection, but Function2 which calls Function1(string, SqlConnection) which then uses the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlFunction` methods like `Function` and `Function2` are actually the interface of your code to SQL Server and shouldn't depend on one another. If they do, its a sign that your code is starting to get too complex for simple static methods.

A better solution would be to leave connection management to the `SqlFunction` methods and put the actual implementation in other methods, eg:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function1(string arg1)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        InnerFunction1(sqlCnn,arg1);
    }
    return true;
}

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static bool Function2(string arg1)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        InnerFunction2(sqlCnn,"arg1");
    }
    return true;
}

private static bool InnerFunction1(SqlConnection sqlCnn,string arg1)
{
        //... Some code here.   
}

private static bool InnerFunction2(SqlConnection sqlCnn,string arg1)
{
        bool ret1 = InnerFunction1(sqlCnn,"arg1");
        //... Some code here.           
}
```

If you have many such functions, you could extract the implementation to other classes as appropriate and keep the static class only to expose the `SqlFunction` members.

Answer (score 0):

Move the function call out of the using block.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).